# NullPointerException when trying to read second column of a csv file

Tags: groovy, soapui

The code below reads off a csv file that consists of two columns. If you view the for loop which is commented out, the code works where it retrieves all the rows of data from the first column. However, when I try to implement the same to happen for the other loop to pick from the second column, I get a 'Null Pointer Exception'.

I notice for the uncommented `for` loop if I change the values from [1] to [0]. it works but obviously I need the [1] to pick form the second column.

I have tried creating two separate csv files and go from there but still getting same error.

Code below:

```
def test1array_properties = [];
def test2array_properties = [];

for(int i = 0; i <= test1_properties.size(); i++) {
        if(!test1_properties[i][0]) {
        break
    } else {
        log.info test1_properties[i][0]
        test1array_properties << test1_properties[i][0]
    }

}


for(int i = 0; i <= test2_properties.size(); i++) {
    if(!test2_properties[i][1]) {
        break
    } else {
        log.error test2_properties[i][1]
        test2array_properties << test2_properties[i][1]
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? the data you have shown resemble to your data? what do you mean `there are more hotels than villas`

Comment: @Rao, I mean in the csv there are more 2 villas and 4 hotels, so some rows will contain null for villas. I have provided an edit below where I am now using 2 CSV files, one for villas, one for hotels. I paste the code but still getting null pointer exception

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145180/room-for-rao-and-bruceybandit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the groovy script, to get required data into respective variables.

This does not use any libraries, just groovy.

```
//This assumes both villas, hotels in the csv file
//Change file name if needed;use absolute path or use property expansion to make it work on other machines.

def filename = 'VillasAndBeach.csv'
def lines = new File(filename).readLines()
def villas = []
def hotels = []
lines.eachWithIndex { line, index ->
    if (index) {
        def data = line.split(',')*.trim()
        if (data[0]) villas << data[0]
        if (data[1]) hotels << data[1]
    }
}

log.info "Villas : ${villas}"
log.info "Hotels: ${hotels}"
```